# Words in CSV are detected in user input

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a program where if the word 'water' is detected in a user input, it will print a solution. I have managed to figure out importing the csv, and using the csv reader and linked it up to some if statements. BUT it only works if I type in the exact word, and not when it's in a sentence or paragraph. I will share my code tomorrow, but any help now would be nice!

Comment: That isn't how StackOverflow works...

Comment: @Abdul you need to share not only your code but also the format of your csv file and what "detected in a user input" means.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I don't really know what I am doing :/

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to answer without any code. [However, you could try using re](https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/regex.html):

```
import re

expr = re.compile(r'.*(?P<word>water),*')

sentence = 'I need some water, please.' #User input here

if expr.findall(sentence):
    print(solution)
```

Comment: OP has tagged with py3 but you link to py2 howto

Comment: Oops, thanks. I just googled for the help documentation to link here, didn't pay the attention to the Python version it came up with. Should work just the same though. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code this is difficult but another option would be to:

```
1.) split the user input based on " "
2.) check if "water" in user_input.lower()
3.) return a solution....

>>>input = "This is a water element"
>>>text = input.split(" ")
>>>text
>>>['This', 'is', 'a', 'water', 'element']
>>>"water" in text
>>>True
>>>"aqua" in text
>>>False
```

Please share your code so we can better gauge this scenario and provide better solutions.